# EXCEPTION: Error during evaluation of "click" occurs only after the 1st click

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework, angular, ionic2

I'm doing a ionic2 http post service.

Using the "(click)" function, my http post will be invoked and everything works the first time. The strange thing happens when I press the button the **2nd time**.

This error pops up:

[image: Error Message]

So i tried to play around with it. I have added a console.log inside my method which the click function is invoked.

On the **3rd time** the button is pressed and so on, there is no error message , neither is my http post is working. Only my console.log inside the method are printing upon click.

[image: Console log]

This is my html:

```
<button  class="button button-block" (click)="loginSuccess()" style="width:70%;">
 <strong>Log In</strong>
</button>
```

This is my js:

```
loginSuccess() {
    console.log("Invoked Meod!");
    this.httpService.loginService("VariablesToThrowOver").subscribe(
    data => {this.httpService = data.results; console.log(data);},
    err => console.log(err),
    () => console.log('Invoked Login Service Complete'));
}
```

And this is my service js:

```
loginService(httpService) {
  console.log("Service Function Variable: "+httpService);
  var body = 'username=' + "admin" + '&password=' + "admin" +'';
  var headers = new Headers();
  headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
  var url = 'http://localhost/webservice/userrWS.asmx/login';
  return this.http.post(url,body, {headers: headers}).map(res => res.json());
}
```

I'm guessing it has something to do with the subscribe service. If that is the case, how do i close the subscribe to allow for a identical request again?

Comment: I can't see any `(click)="xxx"` in your question nor any other information about what function is executed when you click.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Hi, I have edited! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is a bit strange, specially at this line:

```
this.httpService.loginService("VariablesToThrowOver").subscribe(
  data => {this.httpService = data.results; console.log(data);}, // <------
```

In fact, you try to set the received data into the service variable itself you use to execute the login processing. I'm pretty sure that there is no `loginService` method into the object `data.results`. So when you click a second time, you will have an error...

I would choose another (and distinct) property of your component to store this data and display it into the view. Something like this:

```
this.httpService.loginService("VariablesToThrowOver").subscribe(
  data => {
    this.results = data.results; // <------
    console.log(data);
  },
```